Почему картинки при парсинге с соответствующего сайта не могут нормально загрузиться в статью телеграф
Такие дела, при парсинге картинок с сайта "safebooru.org" URL я то получаю, но при вставке этого URL в статью Telegraph, картинка не идентифицирует себя как картинку, то бишь в статье телеграф она не отображается.
Мне нужно, чтобы URL сразу преобразовывалась в картинку в статье телеграф, а не имела неопознанный формат.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from telegraph import Telegraph, upload
import random

import re

article = 'Trying'
author = ''

telegraph = Telegraph()
telegraph.create_account(article, author_name=author)

def post(title, content):
    response = telegraph.create_page(article, author_name=author, html_content = content)
    return 'https://telegra.ph/{}'.format(response['path'])

url = 'https://safebooru.org/index.php?page=post&s=list&tags=eva_01+&pid=42'

response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    
a_tags = soup.find_all('a')
   
ids = [a['id'].lstrip('p') for a in a_tags if 'id' in a.attrs]
    
for id_value in ids:
    print(id_value)

img_links = ''


for id_value in ids:
    url = f'https://safebooru.org/index.php?page=post&s=view&id={id_value}'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    img_tag = soup.find('img', id='image')
    if img_tag and 'src' in img_tag.attrs:
        img_src = img_tag['src'].strip("'")
        img_links += f'<img src="{img_src}"> '
        print(img_src)
postlink = post(article, img_links )
print(postlink)

